# NetworkInfo and WifiConfiguration has been deprecated in SDK 22

Tags: java, android, wifi, deprecated

I'm using android lollipop in PAX A920 device (SDK Version 22). I get a warning message like this when build:

`NetworkInfo in android.net has been deprecated`

`WifiConfiguration in android.net has been deprecated`

I'm confused because I saw an example of sdk 22 in `C:\Users\{YOUR_ACCOUNT}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-22\com\android\connectivitymanagertest`to access wifi using that method, but why does it appear deprecated?

What method is the same to replace the deprecated methods?

```
public boolean isWifiConnected() {
    boolean isWifiConnected = false;
    try {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            isWifiConnected = networkInfo.getState() == CONNECTED;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "wifi adapter is connected? " + isWifiConnected);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isWifiConnected;
}

public void removeNetwork() {
    List<WifiConfiguration> wifiCfgList = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    if (wifiCfgList.size() > 0) {
        for (WifiConfiguration item : wifiCfgList) {
            if (item != null) {
                wifiManager.removeNetwork(item.networkId);
                wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for point out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deprecated classes were repaced with `ConnectivityManager` system service and `NetworkCallbacks`: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type

Even though the official code example shows how to get `NetworkInfo` from `ConnectivityManager` there is a highlighted note:

[image]

Here is a sample code of how you could get the current network state and also receive updates as time goes by. This is a partially stripped-down solution that I would use in production. If you connect it with RxJava or RxKotlin you could create an observable that will hold network state and that will be updated when overridden method of NetworkCallback get called.

Note regarding Java: public class-level variables are made public just for brevity. I'd instead create a few getters for these to access the value behind these variables.

Feel free to ask questions.

Java

```
class NetworkReachabilityService {

    public NetworkType networkType;
    public NetworkState networkState = NetworkState.Unavailable;
    private ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
            super.onAvailable(network);
            updateAvailability(connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network));
        }

        @Override
        public void onLosing(@NonNull Network network, int maxMsToLive) {
            super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive);
            networkState = NetworkState.Losing;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(@NonNull Network network) {
            super.onLost(network);
            networkState = NetworkState.Lost;
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnavailable() {
            super.onUnavailable();
            networkState = NetworkState.Unavailable;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCapabilitiesChanged(@NonNull Network network, @NonNull NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities) {
            super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities);
            updateAvailability(networkCapabilities);
        }
    };

    public NetworkReachabilityService(Context context) {
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }

    private void updateAvailability(NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities) {
        if (networkCapabilities == null) {
            networkState = NetworkState.Unavailable;
            return;
        }

        if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
            networkType = NetworkType.CELL;
        } else if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
            networkType = NetworkType.WiFi;
        }

        networkState = NetworkState.Available;
    }

    public void resumeListeningNetworkChanges() {
        pauseListeningNetworkChanges();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
        } else {
            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(
                    new NetworkRequest.Builder().build(),
                    networkCallback
            );
        }
    }

    public void pauseListeningNetworkChanges() {
        try {
            connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
            // Usually happens only once if: "NetworkCallback was not registered"
        }
    }

    private enum NetworkState {
        Available, Unavailable, Connecting, Losing, Lost
    }

    private enum NetworkType {
        WiFi, CELL, OTHER
    }
}
```

Kotlin

```
sealed class NetworkState {
    data class Available(val type: NetworkType) : NetworkState()
    object Unavailable : NetworkState()
    object Connecting : NetworkState()
    object Losing : NetworkState()
    object Lost : NetworkState()
}

sealed class NetworkType {
    object WiFi : NetworkType()
    object CELL : NetworkType()
    object OTHER : NetworkType()
}

class NetworkReachabilityService private constructor(context: Context) {
    
    private val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    private val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        // There are more functions to override!

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            super.onLost(network)
            networkState = NetworkState.Lost
        }

        override fun onUnavailable() {
            super.onUnavailable()
            networkState = NetworkState.Unavailable
        }

        override fun onLosing(network: Network, maxMsToLive: Int) {
            super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive)
            networkState = NetworkState.Losing
        }

        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            updateAvailability(connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network))
        }

        override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(
            network: Network,
            networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities
        ) {
            super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)
            updateAvailability(networkCapabilities)
        }
    }
    
    var networkState: NetworkState = NetworkState.Unavailable
        private set

    private fun updateAvailability(networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities?) {
        if (networkCapabilities == null) {
            networkState = NetworkState.Unavailable
            return
        }
        var networkType: NetworkType = NetworkType.OTHER

        if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
            networkType = NetworkType.CELL
        }
        if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
            networkType = NetworkType.WiFi
        }

        networkState = NetworkState.Available(networkType)
    }

    fun pauseListeningNetworkChanges() {
        try {
            connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            // Usually happens only once if: "NetworkCallback was not registered"
        }
    }

    fun resumeListeningNetworkChanges() {
        pauseListeningNetworkChanges()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
        } else {
            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(
                NetworkRequest.Builder().build(),
                networkCallback
            )
        }
    }
}
```

To start receiving network state updates call `resumeListeningNetworkChanges` and to stop `pauseListeningNetworkChanges` respectively.

### Update: how to switch between deprecated and new API

Note that even when you use this solution you will anyway have a message that the certain code you use is deprecated! It is completely fine and is not considered as an error as long as you provide an implementation that can switch between new API and old, deprecated API.

Here is an approximate solution. Since the new classes were added in API level 29 we must use `Build.VERSION_CODES.Q` because it is an integer with the value `29`.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {         
   // Use new API here
} else {
   // Use old API here
}
```

Comment: Thank you brother for point out, its worked. What is the replacement for WifiConfiguration to create a network with the configuration we want?

Comment: I tried use WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder but I get error: Call requires API level 29 (current min is 21): new android.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder

Comment: You should be using both: `WifiConfiguration` and `WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder`. Use if-else statement to switch between them. See `resumeListeningNetworkChanges` method in my answer, it uses  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT to determine what API I can call at runtime. The same way you can switch between deprecated and new API. Note, that `WifiConfiguration` became deprecated in API 29. For API 28 and below you should use `WifiConfiguration` because `WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder` will simply not work.

Comment: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT = 22. I'm using NetworkInfo and WifiConfiguration.

A message appears deprecated when using the NetworkInfo and WifiConfiguration libraries, while building.

I tried to replace with the new method (ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback, WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder), and it turns out that the new method is not suitable for SDK 22.

Confused, there is a warning that the library is deprecated but there is no solution for SDK 22.

Comment: Deprecated means there will be no more updates to a feature and it will be removed completely (usually within a few years). It does not mean that your app will break soon, but it might depending on how long a certain feature has been in the deprecated state. It could break only for the most recent versions of Android. I see that you have some misunderstanding. Please, read the following: [description of Deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Deprecated) and [how to handle Deprecated API](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/15008/how-to-handle-deprecated-api)

Comment: [WiFiConfigutaion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration) is deprecated since API 29. [WifiNetworkSpecifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSpecifier) was added in API 29. It means that the deprecated solution will work completely fine until API 29. After API 29 it will work until it is completely removed. 
I'll update my answer a little bit to be clear on that.